# haskell newbie whats wrong with this CLI bmiTell function

Tags: haskell

I get `parse error` on following bmiTell why is that?

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let  bmiTell :: Double -> Double -> String
Prelude| bmiTell weight height
Prelude|   weight / height ^ 2 <= 18.5 = "You're underweight, you emo, you!"
Prelude|   weight / height ^ 2 <= 25.0 = "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet you're ugly!"
Prelude|   weight / height ^ 2 <= 30.0 = "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"
Prelude|   otherwise = "You're a whale, congratulations!"
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:19:1: parse error on input `bmiTell'
```

Comment: You should really type functions this long into a file and load it into ghci rather than trying to type the whole thing into ghci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indenting is throwing off the parser. Take a look at this:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let bmiTell :: Double -> Double -> String
Prelude| bmiTell weight height = undefined
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:6:1: parse error on input `bmiTell'
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let bmiTell :: Double -> Double -> String
Prelude|     bmiTell weight height = undefined
Prelude| :}
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use [guards](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards) in your function definition, so

```
weight / height ^ 2
```

should be

```
| weight / height ^ 2
```

Others are similar.

And as @DiegoNolan pointed out in comment, you really should put this definition in a source file and load it to `ghci`.